# Ruby Initialize and build methods for Object using JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have an object that saves incoming JSON requests in my API, a part of the JSON is the `application_id`, I also keep track of `iteration`, which represents number of API requests by application. I then save the JSON in the `request_params` column.

What I am trying to do is now define a method for each 'key => value' pair in the JSON. So if the JSON looked like this

```
{ 
  "application_id" : 45,
  "student_id" : 88887,
  "school_id" : 1,
  "course_id" : 1 
}
```

It would be cool to be able to say `ri = RequestInteractor.new(request_params: params)` and then using helper methods to access the JSON like this `ri.application_id    #=> 45`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: request_interactors
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  application_id :integer
#  iteration      :integer
#  request_params :json
#  result         :json
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
#

class RequestInteractor < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :increment_iteration

  # Define a helper method for each key in the JSON object.
  request_params.each do |name, value|
    define_method(name) do
      value
    end
  end

  private

  def increment_iteration
    self.iteration = RequestInteractor.where(application_id: application_id).count + 1 || 1
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  end
end
```

the application id I marked above then would be a method that is generated by the `define_method` metablock that should return the JSON value for its `application_id`

I get the following error when trying to access the object through the rails console I get.

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `request_params' for #<Class:0x007fdffc940118>
```

I have made sure my DB is migrated and all the usual checks. I feel like I am missing some fundamental ruby knowledge between ruby classes and classes that inherit from ActiveRecord around the general initialization of the object.

Comment: Its not very clear what you are trying to acheive? Is it some sort of proxying / delegation? Or are you just looking to create a factory method on the class that creates a model instance from JSON input?

Comment: I'd not recommend what you're trying to do here, I once had to refactor a lot of code like that one. The thing is that every time you instantiate a RequestInteractor object, the request_params block will be executed(if you find how to do it), that's a waste of resources(memory, processor, etc). It'd be better if you already know the fields that come in the request(which I think you do), and then create another class/struct and use delegation for that, composition, whatever you want. Other solution is something like you're doing right now, but define the fields once and not for every instance.

Comment: The RequestInteractor(RI) will only ever be instantiated once. @fanta then later on in the API we just go find the RI through its ID. The other option is to use method missing to pull the value out of the JSON, but htis too can bring some hardships later in the debugging process

Comment: cool, you might then need http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html, just in case someone else tries to create more objects. I haven't tried that with an Active Record class though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OpenStruct` like this

```
require 'ostruct'

json = {
  "application_id" => 45,
  "student_id" => 88887,
  "school_id" => 1,
  "course_id" => 1
}

helper = OpenStruct.new(json)
helper.application_id
# => 45
```

Or use `method_missing`

```
@request_params = request_params

def method_missing(sym, *args)
  return @request_params[sym.to_s] if @request_params[sym.to_s]
  super
end
```

Comment: This is pretty much converting a `JSON` object into an `OpenStruct` object so in order to access the value's I have to go somewhere, I would like to flatten the JSON data onto the model so that the model itself has access to the information. so going `ri = RequestInteractor.new(request_params: params)` then `ri.application_id` and not `ri.helper.application_id`

Comment: @TheLegend Mazbe use `method_missing`